# Finding if an edge lies within a set of disjoint rectangles

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, computational-geometry

I'm using a triangulation library to compute the Constrained Delaunay Triangulation of a set of rectangles within some large boundary. The algorithm returns all the edges, but also adds edges inside of the rectangles that define the constraints. I want to be able to find if an edge lies inside of a rectangle in O(1) time.

Here's a more general description of the problem I want to solve. Given a set of nonoverlapping rectangles (the borders of the rectangles may touch) and an edge e with endpoints (x1,y1) and (x2, y2), find in O(1) time if e lies within any of the rectangles (including the border).

Also let me know of any data structures I can use for speedups! I'm also implementing this in java so I have easy access to hash sets, maps and all those nice data structures.

Comment: I think there is no O(1) algorithm for that.  A good data structure is a [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_tree).

Answer (score 0):

Since the rectangles are completely enclosed, the inside of each rectangle will simply be the CDT of the rectangle itself -- which is to say, two triangles, meeting along a diagonal of the rectangle. So you can just insert all rectangles' diagonals (remember, two possible diagonals per rectangle) into a hashtable, and check which edges exactly match those endpoints.

Comment: That isn't true. If there are any rectangles that touch the border, extra edges can be inserted that aren't part of the CDT of the polygon. Check out this other post where I included a visual example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706947/rectangular-constraints-in-delaunay-triangulation-without-edges-within?noredirect=1#comment32823455_21706947

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to break up the area that all of the rectangles cover into a N by M grid of boxes. By labeling each box with the rectangle it is in or the rectangles it overlaps. It is possible to obtain O(1) queries, with O(N*M) pre-processing.

However, in order for it to work, the grid has to created based on an algorithm that allows for calculating which box a point lies in in O(1). It also requires that the number of rectangles a box overlaps be very small (ideally no more than 2 or 3) as otherwise the average query time could be O(log N) or worst. This means that the number of boxes can get very large.